# Open specific excel file/sheet to get a specific content cell location

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I have a list of excel files and their corresponding sheet number. I need python to go to those sheets and find out the cell location for a particular content. Can someone point out the error in my code? Thanks in advance

```
import xlrd
value = 'Avg.'
filename = ('C:/002 Av SW W of 065 St SW 2011-Jul-05.xls', 'C:/003 Avenue SW West of 058 Street SW 2012-Jun-23.xls')
sheetnumber = ('505840', '505608')
dictionary = dict(zip(filename, sheetnumber))
for item in dictionary:
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(item)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(dictionary[key])
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value:
                print row, column
```

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors?

Comment: It says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tsengineer/Desktop/Joydip Trial/Experiment/OpenWorksheet.py", line 8, in <module>
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(dictionary[key])
KeyError: 'C:/004 Avenue SW West of 050 Street SW 2012-Sep-07.xls'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make a dictionary. Iterate over `zip(filename, sheetnumber)`:

```
for name, sheet_name in zip(filename, sheetnumber):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(name)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(sheet.ncols):
            if sheet.cell(row,column).value == value:
                print row, column
```

Comment: Instead of writing down the filename and sheetnumber, I wanted python to grab them from an excel sheet. I created two tuples to grab the filename and sheetnumber from the excel sheet. But when I include it with your previous code, it does not print me the row and column number. Any ideas? Looks like I cannot post my updated code here as I am a new user.

Comment: @Joydip it would be better to elaborate it into a separate SO question so that more people could look at it. Thanks.